# How to select multiple rows in a datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following datatable:

http://live.datatables.net/vepedopa/40/edit

When I select a row, if I want to select another one the previous selected row is unchecked.

`selectAll` works great, but what if I want to select two rows instead of just one?

What I've tried:
I was reading about the [select.selector()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/select.selector()) function and tried to modify the `selector` to select only `td` instead of `td:first-child`:

```
    select: {
        style: 'os',
        selector: 'td'
    },
```

But apparently that was not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you selected 'os' as the style of selection, this will depend on your system. For windows, you can select multiple rows by holding keys like `CTRL` and `SHIFT`

If you just want to select multiple rows by clicking the rows, use the 'multi' style

```
select: {
    style: 'multi',
    selector: 'td'
},
```

There is also a `multi+shift` style that is a hybrid of both, allowing you to use modifier keys and clicking on rows without losing previously selected rows.